# Default vhost settings in puppetlabs-apache

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm trying to set default options for all vhosts. The documentation says "All of the SSL parameters for ::vhost will default to whatever is set in the base apache class" (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#ssl-parameters-for-apachevhost). However, this does not work:

```
class { '::apache':
    ssl_protocol => 'all -SSLv2 -SSLv3',
}
```

It throws "Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter ssl_protocol on Class[Apache]"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssl_protocol` parameter is part of the `Apache::Vhost` defined type. Not part of the `apache` class.

You can set the defaults with the following:

```
 Apache::Vhost { ssl_protocol => 'all -SSLv2 -SSLv3' }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uhm, what? `Apache { ... }` is no way to declare "default" parameter values for the `apache` class. That would not make sense - there can be only one `class { 'apache': }` anyway. Apparently you *can* declare defaults for **all** classes you declare using `Class { param => value, ... }`. I would personally steer clear of that, though. It looks pretty dangerous.

Comment: @FelixFrank Your correct. sorry about that. Wasn't paying much attention and in my mind the separation of defined type and class wasn't clear. editing anser